# Как, при помощи ctrl + left/right arrow, сделать переход не только в начало слова, но и в конец

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

Я раньше работала с Atom, в котором с этими переходами проблем не было. Сейчас выполняю посредственные задачи, с которыми справится и встроенный IDLE Python. Но проблема в том, что он, при нажатии ctrl left/right arrow, переходит только в начало слова. Как мне это настроить, чтобы было также, как и на Atom'е?

[image]

Comment: Если честно,не особо понял вопроса,но я делаю это с помощью ctrl + End/Home(если речь идет конечно же о начале и конце строки)

Comment: Видимо никак, если вы работаете в удивительном IDLE )

Answer (score 0):

У меня все работает: `ctrl left arrow` переходит в начало слова, `ctrl right arrow` в конец.

Я использую Python 3.8, возможно в ранних версиях это не исправили.